# Probability - can't understand odd function (random variable prob.)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, means, even-and-odd-functions

[PROBLEM PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YOG0.png)

Hello, I do not understand above pictures's "ODD FUNCTION => 0" part.

I need more detailed explanation on how it becomes to be 0.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The integral of an odd (and integrable) function over a domain symmetric about zero is zero, intuitively because $f(x)$ cancels with $f(-x)$ for each $x$.

Comment: Hi, then why right side's "mean * integral...dx" part is 1?

Comment: The second part is not odd (there is no factor of $z$ there), and in fact it is just the integral of the density function which is necessarily $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An odd function is symmetric with respect to the origin.

Mathematically speaking you have $f(x)=-f(-x)$

Consider a function like $f(x)=x^3$,and try to find the integral on $(-1,1)$.

This is an example of odd function where you get the same quantity of negative as positive so the  total integral is $0$

The function in your problem is an odd function because $f(z)=-f(-z)$ so the total integral on $(-\infty, \infty ) =0$